# Finding whether $f(x) = 2x+[x]+\sin x \cos x$ is increasing or decreasing.

Tags: functions, derivatives, random-graphs

I want to determine whether the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $f(x) = 2x+[x]+\sin x \cos x$ is increasing or decreasing, where $[\cdot]$ denotes the  Greatest Integer Function.

I only know the derivative method for checking whether it's increasing or decreasing. But here how do I find the derivative of this function. We are supposed to answer this without using any graphical devices.

Comment: You can still differentiate it _almost_ everywhere. Then you have to check by hand the non-differentiable points.

Comment: Lett $g(x) = 2x + \sin(x)\cos(x)$. You can use calculus to show $g$ is increasing, and that shows $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also know the definition of increasing.

It is straightforward to see that the greatest integer less than or equal to a given integer is constant almost everywhere and jumps at the integers.  So its derivative is
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} [x] = 0, x \in \Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Z}  $$
and is undefined on the integers.

Then, on $\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Z}$, 
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( 2x + [x] + \sin x \cos x \right) = 2+0+\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x  \text{.}  $$
Cosine and sine are bounded and we know $\cos^2 x \in [0,1]$ and $\sin^2 x \in [0,1]$.  so this derivative is bonded below by $2+0-1 = 1$.  Consequently, this derivitive is positive on $\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Z}$.  That is, on each open interval $(n,n+1)$ with $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, $f$ is increasing.

Let $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and consider the limits of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $n$ from the left and right.  The continuous terms of $f$ are easy to deal with.  The greatest integer function increase from $n-1$ immediately to the left of $n$ to $n$ immediately to the right of $n$.  \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow n^-} f(x) &= 2n + (n-1) + \cos n \sin n  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow n^+} f(x) &= 2n + n + \cos n \sin n
\end{align*}
So we see that $f$ is increases (by $1$) at integral points of its domain.

Therefore, $f$ is increasing.